# Github doesn't me to create pull requests from my old local branch saying "There isn’t anything to compare."

Tags: git, github

1. Two months ago I create a new local branch `foo` from `master` using `git checkout -b foo`. And I have been developing in `foo`
2. Today I finished developing. I `git push` in `foo` but github says that

> There isn’t anything to compare.
>
> master and foo are entirely different commit histories.

I cannot view the diff, the changed files and I can't create a pull request. The web page doesn't allow me to do that.

3. I tried to `git rebase origin/master` in `foo` but ended up with thousands of conflicts in files I never touched.

How can I fix this and how do I avoid this situation in the future?

Answer (score 0):

This implies that:

- you rewrote your commit history reachable from `foo`, and/or
- someone rewrote the commit history reachable from `master` over on `origin`.

In general, the way to recover from this is to rebase the commits that are strictly yours, excluding all commits that were theirs, `--onto` the appropriate commit in their updated master.  That is, suppose they are the ones who rewrote commit history.  You ran:

```
git clone <url>
```

and got:

```
A--B--...--R   <-- master (HEAD), origin/master
```

You then created your branch `foo` pointing to original commit `R` (each uppercase letter here stands in for some hash ID):

```
A--B--...--R   <-- foo (HEAD), master, origin/master
```

You then created a series of new commits:

```
A--B--...--R   <-- master, origin/master
            \
             S--T   <-- foo (HEAD)
```

(but probably longer than this).  Meanwhile someone else, who controls the `origin` repository, decided that for some reason, they hate something about commit `A` and they needed to replace commit `A` with a new-and-improved `A'` (different hash ID, and probably a different snapshot).  This made it necessary for them to replace `B` with a new and improved `B'` that sits atop `A'`, and so on, all the way down to `R`.

You then use `git fetch` (perhaps via `git pull`) to bring in their new commits; your Git updates your `origin/master` to point to the last of the new commits, and in the meantime they added one new commit `U`:

```
A'-B'-...--R'-U   <-- origin/master

A--B--...--R   <-- master
            \
             S--T   <-- foo (HEAD)
```

Your branch's history—the history that ends at `T` on `foo`—begins with commit `A` and runs all the way to commit `T`.  Their branch's history for `master`, which ends at `U`, now starts at `A'`, which has *no relationship* to commit `A`.  So `git merge` cannot do anything as there is no common starting point.

To recover from this, you would want to copy your commits `S` and `T`—those being the ones *you made*, not the ones you got with your initial `git clone`—to new-and-improved `S'` and `T'`.  These may fit easily after `U`, which could be your final end goal, but they are more *likely* to fit easily after `R'`, `origin`'s replacement for `R`.  So you would now run:

```
git switch foo    # if / as needed
git rebase --onto origin/master <hash-of-R>
```

or:

```
git rebase --onto origin/master master
```

(if you have not changed where your own name `master` points, so that your `master` still remembers which commit you started with as you began to make new commits on `foo`).

Assuming this works—though it may have a few merge conflicts along the way for you to solve—you'll end up with this in your own repository:

```
              S'-T'  <-- foo (HEAD)
             /
A'-B'-...--R'-U   <-- origin/master

A--B--...--R   <-- master
            \
             S--T   <-- origin/foo [since you had pushed foo earlier]
```

You can now `git push --force-with-lease origin foo` to force *their* `foo` (your `origin/foo`) to move so that it points to `T'`, abandoning your original `S-T` chain of commits entirely.  Now their branch tip `U` and your branch tip `T'` have a common starting point, namely commit `R'`, and now you can make a PR on GitHub.

(If *you're* the one who rewrote history, perhaps through an inappropriate filter-branch or filter-repo or just an inappropriate `git rebase`, the process is still essentially the same: you need to figure out which commits are *yours* and copy just those commits.  Use `git log --graph` and/or see [Pretty Git branch graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1057564/1256452) for ways for helping figure out which commits those are, if the simple "my `master` branch name" trick is no longer usable.)